# boot strap overriding customized nav-bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

With out bootstrap the nav bar works perfectly fine, but when I activate bootstrap the nav bar gets buggy.

Here is how it should look:
[image]

Here is how it looks with bootstrap:
[image]

I think there is something that needs an `!important` added to it, but I'm not sure what so please can someone with experience tell me which one?

I tried `inline-flex` as well but still no hope
I tried `!important` with the width but still doesn't work
I tried `height: 0%!important;` and still nothing work

I need to use bootstrap to have the table with bootstrap design so removing bootstrap is no option.

ok so I'm not sure if there's another problem like this but can't seem to find an answer so here is my code:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#extra space {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#section2 {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5em 0 5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: 125% auto;
}

#section2 header {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 12vh;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
  overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex!important;
  justify-content: space-around!important;
  width: 100%!important;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 3px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .nav-links {
    font-size: 1px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {}
  .burger {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  .nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

#section1 {
  background-image: url("background6.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
}

#section2 {
  background-image: url("background image venuto4.jpg");
  height: 980px;
  width: 100%;
}

#section3 {
  background-color: black;
  height: 700px;
}

#section4 {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  height: 700px;
}

#section5 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Overflow by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>

<head>
  <title>Overflow by HTML5 UP</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navmain.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstap.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/703d63b52b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4>thomas<br> venutu</h4>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">NextEvent</a> </li>
      <li><a href="index">Music </a> </li>
      <li><a href="index">About</a> </li>
      <li><a href="index">Boooking</a> </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section id="section1">

  </section>
  <section id="section2">


    <header>
      <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
      <h2>Next event</h2>
      <h3>Venue At:</h3>
      <h4>TBA</h4>
    </header>
    <div id="getting-started">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 m-auto offset-lg-3 col-lg-5">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <table class="table" summary="date and time for the next event">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Days</th>
                      <th>Hours</th>
                      <th>Minutes</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td id="day" class="display-4"></td>
                      <td id="hours" class="display-4"></td>
                      <td id="minutes" class="display-4"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/main2.js"></script>
    <!--conection to main.js !-->
  </section>

  <section id="section3">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="section4">
    <h1>Music</h1>
    <article class="container box style2">
      <div class="row gtr-0">
        <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile">
          <a href="icon brands fa-facebook-f" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1798697_10202102944072424_1617307970_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile">
          <a href="images/fulls/06.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1898181_10202102918071774_1708501880_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile">
          <a href="images/fulls/07.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1901776_10202102917311755_760656742_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile">
          <a href="images/fulls/08.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/10275374_10202690394478317_8154904436564081527_o.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  <div id="section5"></div>
  <section>
    <h1>home</h1>
  </section>
  <script src="navbarjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

edit:
the answer is you need to do a bootstrap nav_bar

the good thing if you search in the answers bellow you find my accepted answer as a good navbar

Comment: Please consider using a better title. Usually you should anticipate what other people might search in the future when they have a similar problem.

Comment: i will do that sorry but i was kinda mad haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your structure as `bootstrap` have its own `nav` structure so you need to follow that.

I just change the `nav` with the `bootstrap` `nav` and added you links

```css
html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#extra space{
 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar-nav {
    justify-content: space-around;
 width: 100%;
}
#section2 {
  
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5em 0 5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: 125% auto;
 }



#section2 header {
   margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  }


 *{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{
position:sticky;
top:0;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;
min-height: 12vh;
background-color: #0c0c0c;
 overflow: auto;
}

.logo{
 color:whitesmoke;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 font-size:22px;
}

.nav-links{
 display:flex!important;
 justify-content: space-around!important;
 width: 100%!important;
 
  
}
.nav-links li{
 list-style: none;
}

.burger div{
 width: 25px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color:whitesmoke;
 margin:3px;
}
.burger{
 display:none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links a{
color:whitesmoke;
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 3px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
 .nav-links{
 display:inline-flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 width: 60%;
 
  
}
 
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
 body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
 }
 .nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
 }
 .nav-links{
  font-size: 1px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0px;
  height:92vh;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
 }
 .nav-links li{
 
 }
 
 .burger{
  display: block;
   position: absolute;
         top: 8px;
         right: 16px;
        
 }
 
 .nav-active{
 transform: translateX(0%);
 }
}
#section1 {
 background-image: url("background6.png");
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 background-color:black;
 
 
}
#section2 {
 background-image:url("background image venuto4.jpg");
 height: 980px;
 width: 100%;
}
#section3 {
 background-color: black;
 height: 700px;
}
#section4 {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 height: 700px;

}
#section5 {
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
 Overflow by HTML5 UP
 html5up.net | @ajlkn
 Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Overflow by HTML5 UP</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navmain.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstap.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/703d63b52b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
 </head>

 <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><div class="logo">
    <h4>thomas<br> venutu</h4>

   </div></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">NextEvent</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index">Music</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index">Boooking</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
  <section id="section1">
   
  </section>
  <section id="section2"> 
    
   
   <header>
    <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
     <h2>Next event</h2>
     <h3>Venue At:</h3>
     <h4>TBA</h4>
    </header>
    <div id="getting-started">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 m-auto offset-lg-3 col-lg-5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-body">
              <table class="table" summary="date and time for the next event">
                <tr>
                  <th>Days</th>
                  <th>Hours</th>
                  <th>Minutes</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id="day" class="display-4"></td>
                  <td id="hours" class="display-4"></td>
                  <td id="minutes" class="display-4"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/jquery.countdown.js"></script> 
<script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/main2.js"></script> <!--conection to main.js !-->
  </section>
  
  <section id="section3">
   <h1>About</h1>
  </section>
  
  <section id="section4">
   <h1>Music</h1>
   <article class="container box style2">
   <div class="row gtr-0">
      <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="icon brands fa-facebook-f" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1798697_10202102944072424_1617307970_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a></div>
      <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/06.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1898181_10202102918071774_1708501880_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a></div>
      <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/07.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1901776_10202102917311755_760656742_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a></div>
      <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/08.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/10275374_10202690394478317_8154904436564081527_o.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a></div>
     </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  <div id="section5"></div>
  <section>
   <h1>home</h1>
  </section>
  <script src="navbarjs.js"></script>
 </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: wow thats alot of work can you tell me if its possible to just disable the bootstrap for just the nav bar ?

Comment: @victor Nope not for the nav it includes in the project and as you use `nav` tag of html it has its own style in bootstrap, But you can override those default rules but in my opinion thats a heck-tech job to do:)

Comment: ok then i guess i have to redo the navbar to bootstrap thanks a lot this will help me

Comment: @victor YES as its responsive, and and its help a lot in future for you code, like you can use its responsive grid, buttons, modals and a lot more.. And accept it as an answer if that helps just to help others who view your post :)

Comment: i just hoped there was remove boot strap for this div kinda code :P

Comment: Actually when you use some frame work like `bootstrap` `material-design` etc they are complete package if you only need its single component you need to include that all, that's how they work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#extra space{
 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#section2 {
  
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5em 0 5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: 125% auto;
 }



#section2 header {
   margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  }


 *{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  min-height: 12vh;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}

.logo{
 color:whitesmoke;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 font-size:22px;
}

.nav-links{
 display:flex!important;
 justify-content: space-around!important;
 width: 100%!important;
 
  
}
.nav-links li{
 list-style: none;
}

.burger div{
 width: 25px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color:whitesmoke;
 margin:3px;
}
.burger{
 display:none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links a{
color:whitesmoke;
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 3px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
 .nav-links{
 display:inline-flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 width: 60%;
 
  
}
 
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
 body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
 }
 .nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
 }
 .nav-links{
  font-size: 1px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0px;
  height:92vh;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
 }
 .nav-links li{
 
 }
 
 .burger{
  display: block;
   position: absolute;
         top: 8px;
         right: 16px;
        
 }
 
 .nav-active{
 transform: translateX(0%);
 }
}
#section1 {
 background-image: url("background6.png");
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 background-color:black;
 
 
}
#section2 {
 background-image:url("background image venuto4.jpg");
 height: 980px;
 width: 100%;
}
#section3 {
 background-color: black;
 height: 700px;
}
#section4 {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 height: 700px;

}
#section5 {
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
 Overflow by HTML5 UP
 html5up.net | @ajlkn
 Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Overflow by HTML5 UP</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navmain.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstap.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/703d63b52b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
 </head>

 <body>
  <header class="header d-flex align-items-center container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-center flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-auto">
          <div class="logo">
      <h4>thomas<br> venutu</h4>
       </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <nav>   
         <ul class="nav-links">
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">NextEvent</a> </li>
          <li><a href="index">Music </a> </li>
          <li><a href="index">About</a> </li>
          <li><a href="index">Boooking</a> </li>
         </ul>

         <div class="burger">
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
         </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  
  <section id="section1">
   
  </section>
  <section id="section2"> 
    
   
   <header>
    <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
     <h2>Next event</h2>
     <h3>Venue At:</h3>
     <h4>TBA</h4>
    </header>
    <div id="getting-started">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 m-auto offset-lg-3 col-lg-5">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-body">
              <table class="table" summary="date and time for the next event">
                <tr>
                  <th>Days</th>
                  <th>Hours</th>
                  <th>Minutes</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id="day" class="display-4"></td>
                  <td id="hours" class="display-4"></td>
                  <td id="minutes" class="display-4"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/jquery.countdown.js"></script> 
<script src="../../Downloads/mftp_zip_2020_03_11_02_16_39/htdocs/assets/venuto/main2.js"></script> <!--conection to main.js !-->
  </section>
  
  <section id="section3">
   <h1>About</h1>
  </section>
  
  <section id="section4">
   <h1>Music</h1>
   <article class="container box style2">
   <div class="row gtr-0">
      <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="icon brands fa-facebook-f" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1798697_10202102944072424_1617307970_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a></div>
      <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/06.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1898181_10202102918071774_1708501880_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a></div>
      <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/07.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/1901776_10202102917311755_760656742_n.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a></div>
      <div class="col-3 col-12-mobile"><a href="images/fulls/08.jpg" class="image fit"><img src="images/venuto/10275374_10202690394478317_8154904436564081527_o.jpg" alt="" title="still in proggress" /></a></div>
     </div>
    </article>
  </section>
  <div id="section5"></div>
  <section>
   <h1>home</h1>
  </section>
  <script src="navbarjs.js"></script>
 </body> 

</html>
```

Comment: You should explain what you did so that the OP can understand what was wrong and avoid doing the mistake next time

Comment: when i copy the code it  dosnt work but with your run code on snipet it works